# Calculate and display stratified sampling points in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I am trying to generate 100 random points in Global Forest Watch data over my region of interest (ROI). I think I was able to successfully generate the points as a feature collection, as I don't get any errors. But when I use addLayer() to examine my points, the geemap renders but does not show any points. Is it possible that I didn't create the stratified sample points that I want? Or am I just not correctly visualizing them?

```
HANSEN = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8")
LOSS = hansen_map.select('lossyear').clip(ROI)
GFW = ee.Image(0).where(LOSS_MAP.gt(19), 1).clip(ROI) #this remap is just because I only care about loss in 2020 not earlier

points = GFW.stratifiedSample(
  numPoints=100, 
  classBand='constant',
  scale=4
)

points = ee.FeatureCollection(points).flatten(); 

Ac_map = geemap.Map()
Ac_map.centerObject(ROI, 11)
Ac_map.addLayer(points,{},'Validation Points')
Ac_map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `geometries` to `true` in `stratifiedSample()`. Otherwise, the samples will not include the geometries, and you cannot put them on a map. If you print your points, you'll see that the features miss their geometry.

You also have some issues with variable names, and that `flatten()` call on the points - that causes an error, since you don't actually have nested feature collections to flatten.

In JavaScript:

```
var ROI = Map.getBounds(true)
var HANSEN = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8")
var LOSS = HANSEN.select('lossyear').clip(ROI)
var GFW = LOSS.gt(19)

var points = GFW.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100, 
  classBand: 'lossyear',
  scale: 4,
  geometries: true
})

print(points)
Map.addLayer(points,{},'Validation Points')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b034cef61b2216876f2f60aa08025ac6

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. I'm still learning to wrap my head around scripting and really appreciate this